# Background service issue in oreo and pie

Tags: java, android, background-service, jobintentservice

Basically i want to send latitude and longitude in background it is working fine below Oreo versions but I am stuck in that part. It is working all good. I have added a background JobIntentService it is working fine in Oreo and pie background but when I lock the screen after 2 minutes it disable or stop sending location to my server.

```
public class LocationService extends JobIntentService implements LocationListener {

static final int JOB_ID = 1000; //Unique job ID.
RequestQueue requestQueue;
DBConnection con;
String Lat, Lng;
public static final int notify = 5000;  //interval between two services(Here Service run every 5 Minute)
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();   //run on another Thread to avoid crash
private Timer mTimer = null;
protected LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
   onGetLocation();
    if (mTimer != null) // Cancel if already existed
        mTimer.cancel();
    else
        mTimer = new Timer();   //recreate new
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new LocationService.TimeDisplay(), 0, notify);   //Schedule task

}
public LocationService() {

}
public static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent work) {
    enqueueWork(context, LocationService.class, JOB_ID, work);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {
   UpdateLocation();

}
public void UpdateLocation()
{
    con = new DBConnection(LocationService.this);

    if(requestQueue==null) {
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext(), new StethoVolleyHurlStack());
    }
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            "https://example.com/api/" + "updatelocation.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("Response", response.toString() + " " + Lat.toString()+ " " + Lng.toString());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("Response", error.toString());
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("userid", con.getusename());
            map.put("lat", Lat);
            map.put("lng", Lng);

            return map;
        }
    };

    requestQueue.add(request);
}
public void onGetLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&      ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    Lng=String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
    Lat=String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
}

class TimeDisplay extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        // run on another thread
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                UpdateLocation();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide little bit of code hear get more idea about your problem.

Comment: @ViralPatel please check

Comment: I hope it'll help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49497032

Comment: Do you use a real device for testing? Some manufacturers (e.g. Huawei) implement very aggressive background execution policies. As far as I know there is no other way to deal with this problem than adding an exception for your app in the system settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to add notification on start you service

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements CallbackResponseListener, LocationListener {

public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
        }
        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
            Log.e("Service Started", "onStartCommand!");
            createNotificationChannel();
            startTimer();
            return START_STICKY;
        }
     private void createNotificationChannel() {
            // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
            // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                CharSequence name = "Service channel";
                String description = "Service channel description";
                int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("12", name, importance);
                channel.setDescription(description);
                // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
                // or other notification behaviors after this
                NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

            PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                    notificationIntent, 0);
            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "12")
                    .setContentTitle("Title")
                    .setContentText("App is running in background for location")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon).setContentIntent(intent)
                    .build();
            startForeground(2001, notification);
        }
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            Log.e("Service EXIT", "ondestroy!");    
                Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationBroadcastReceiver.class);
                sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

            stoptimertask();
        }


        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }
     public void startTimer() {
            //set a new Timer
            try {
                timer = new Timer();   
                //initialize the TimerTask's job
                initializeTimerTask(); 
                //schedule the timer, to wake up every 1 second
                timer.schedule(timerTask, AppConstants.bgTaskStartDelay,2000); //
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
 /**
     * it sets the timer to print the counter every x seconds
     */
    public void initializeTimerTask() {
        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // add your code here for schedule




                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Notification also stopped after 2 mins.

Comment: Then you can try with simple service extend with your class this is working fine for me

Comment: Thanks for your effort I already did the same thing yesterday it works!! Thanks